# Mysterious error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘case’

Tags: c

```
  case CON_QCLASS:
    if ((GET_CLASS(d->character) = parse_class(*arg)) == CLASS_UNDEFINED) {
      SEND_TO_Q("\r\nThat's not a class.\r\nClass: ", d);
      return;
    else
    SEND_TO_Q(race_menu, d);
    SEND_TO_Q("\r\nRace: ", d);
    STATE(d) = CON_QRACE;
    break;

  case CON_QRACE:
    if ((GET_RACE(d->character) = parse_race(*arg)) == CLASS_UNDEFINED) {
      SEND_TO_Q("\r\nThat's not a race.\r\nRace: ", d);
      return;


    if (GETPFILEPOS(d->character) < 0)
      GETPFILEPOS(d->character) = create_entry(GET_NAME(d->character);
    init_char(d->character);
    save_char(d->character, NOWHERE);
    SEND_TO_Q(motd, d);
    SEND_TO_Q("\r\n\n*** PRESS RETURN: ", d);
    STATE(d) = CON_RMOTD;

    sprintf(buf, "%s [%s] new player.", GET_NAME(d->character), d->host);
    mudlog(buf, NRM, LVL_IMMORT, TRUE);
    break;
```

This is the error I get.

```
interpreter.c:71:3: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘case’`enter code here`
```

The top line is the offending party. I thought maybe I forgot something, like a bracket/bracer/parenthesis above it, but that doesn't seem to be the case. At least I'm guessing so, since the error occurred only after adding the above code.

EDIT: Sorry for wasting your time, I realized my mistake. I ended up putting it a few sections above where I had meant it to, totally replacing a part of my code. I feel stupid now. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing closing braces `}` for the if statements at the beginning of each case section.

Answer (score 0):

`if ((GET_CLASS(d->character) = parse_class(*arg)) == CLASS_UNDEFINED) {`

forget `}` other too.